# Realizar INNER JOIN correctamente

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas `t1=quotations` y `t2=quotation_has_packinglist` en las que he repetido los campos `email` y `date`, con el objeto de poder obtener la información de la tabla `quotation_has_packinglist` y mostrarla en la vista donde muestro las opciones de la tabla `quotations` siempre y cuando el `email` y la fecha `date` sean iguales.
Lo que tengo actualmente es

```
SELECT quotation_has_packinglist.* FROM quotation_has_packinglist, quotations WHERE quotations.email = quotation_has_packinglist.email
```

Pero me trae a la vista toda la información de la tabla `'quotation_has_packinglist'`, no hace el filtro por `'email'` y `'date'`.
Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. Gracias!

Edito la entrada para agregar mayor información, según lo solicitado por @Aaron:
Lo que quiero lograr se muestra en la siguiente imagen, en la parte superior mostrando el contenido de las 2 tablas relacionando por email y date:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis tablas tienen la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en ambas tablas he dejado los campos email y date con el mismo nombre y como índice para que sea más fácil encontrar relacionar sus datos.
Mi controlador si habilito la línea con email y fecha proporcionada (fija) muestra correctamente lo que necesito, pero no de forma dinámica; pero si la comento y descomento la línea donde se hace el JOIN proporcionado por la primera respuesta de este hilo no muestra nada en la parte baja, es decir no trae las opciones a la variable $packinglist.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente el código de la vista donde se muestra en la primera imagen la parte superior y en la segunda imagen la parte inferior, donde quiero mostrar las opciones del Packing List:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con Codeigniter (MVC).
El modelo no lo incluyo ya que está codificado con ActiveRecords, pero se demuestra en las imágenes que está entregando la información, y lo que falta solamente es que el JOIN en el controlador debe ser realizado correctamente para que muestre lo que necesito, de ah´el título de mi pregunta "cómo poder realizar el JOIN correctamente".  Gracias de antemano por sus propuestas de solución. Saludos!!

Comment: Debes ser mas especifico con lo que preguntas y con lo que planteas, deberías de mostrar cuales son los campos de ambas tablas, así es mas fácil poder ayudarte..

Comment: @Aaron me has solicitado más antecedentes, los he agregado hace un par de días, podrías ahora ayudarme con este código? Gracias.

Comment: Creo que el problema viene desde que el diseño de tus tablas esta mal, dado que no puede (o debe) haber dos indices o llaves primarias en cada tabla y tu tienes dos en la primera tabla y tres  en la segunda tabla, por lo que hacer la consulta (Con las tablas tal como las tienes) que buscas es algo complicad... no me queda muy claro, si crees que este pasando algo por alto comentalo y así poderte ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres hacer un inner join de ambas tablas según lo que planteas debería ser así:

```
SELECT quotation_has_packinglist.* 
FROM quotation_has_packinglist 
INNER JOIN
    quotations ON quotations.email = quotation_has_packinglist.email 
AND 
    quotations.date = quotation_has_packinglist.date
```

Al parecer en tu consulta no estas usando el filtro de fecha ni inner join, estás cruzando las dos tablas por un campo que no determina ninguna diferencia porque ambos pueden ser iguales en toda la tabla por eso parece que no hiciera filtro.

Comment: Hola @Fredy, he implementado el código pero no me trae nada a la vista, entiendo que está bien redactado, quizá sea otro el motivo que no me muestra la información, pero la vista queda vacía.. :(